# Problems with Ubuntu system update

Tags: updates, repository

Anytime I want to update my Ubuntu system, it gives me the errors shown below:

```
Error while refreshing cache

pk-client-error-quark: W: GPG error: https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal lnRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO _PUBKEY DE19EB17684BA42D 
E: The repository 'https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal lnRelease' is not signed. 
w: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. 
W: See apt-secure(S) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal lnRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO _PUBKEY DE19EB17684BA42D) (319)
```

Comment: Have you followed this instructions correctly? https://apt.kitware.com/

Comment: yes , but the problem is continue

Comment: What happened exactly when you did #2 (obtain the repo's key)? Any error message?